# Preencher combobox com dados do SQL Server Compact

Tags: c#, sql-server

Preciso preencher um combobox com dados de uma coluna do SQL Server Compact, o código que tenho não funcionou.

Classe `Servidor.cs`:

```
public DataTable Load(string sql)
    {
        Servidor objSqlCeServerDAL = Servidor.GetInstance(connString);
        objSqlCeServerDAL.Open();
        SqlCeDataAdapter dAd = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sql, objSqlCeConnection);
        dAd.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            dAd.Fill(dSet, "servidor");
            return dSet.Tables["servidor"];
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dSet.Dispose();
            dAd.Dispose();
            objSqlCeServerDAL.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Form configurações:

```
try
        {
            Servidor s2 = new Servidor();
            cbServidores.DataSource = s2.Load("Select * from servidor");
            cbServidores.DisplayMember = "servidor";
            cbServidores.ValueMember = "id";
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cadastre um servidor!");
        }
```

O nome do banco é: config-data.sdf / tabela: servidor / colunas: id, servidor, banco, usuário, senha.

Comment: O que não funcionou? O que esperava e o que resultou?

Comment: @bigown Eu esperava preencher o ComboBox com todos os dados da coluna "servidor" do banco de dados, porém esses dados não aparecem

Comment: @MarlonLeandro: Poderia informar o nome do banco de dados, o nome da tabela e o nome da coluna? // Evite construções do tipo SELECT *

Comment: @JoséDiz Editei a pergunda, adicionei os detalhes